# 'BOT' is not recognized as an internal command or external command, an executable program or a command file

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, discord, bots

I'm trying to run a discord bot that I found on GitHub. I use Windows, the program uses Docker, Node, and maybe some other things I'm not aware of.

When I run the program with "node start-bots.js", cmd gives me an error:

> 'BOT' is not recognized as an internal command or external command, an executable program or a command file.

I tried many things but nothing works...

Here is the code of the start-bot.js :

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const bots = require('./bots.json');

const recreate = () => {

    console.log(` Checking existing volumes...`);

    exec(`docker volume ls -q`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {

        const volumes = stdout.split('\n');

        bots.forEach((bot) => {
            console.log(` Starting ${bot.name}...`);

            const start = () => {
                exec(`BOT=${bot.name} VINTED_BOT_ADMIN_IDS=${bot.adminIDs}           
VINTED_BOT_TOKEN=${bot.token} docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -p                 
bot-${bot.name} up -d`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(` ${bot.name} failed to start.`);
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(stderr);
                });
        }    
        
        if (volumes.includes(`bot-${bot.name}`)) {
            console.log(` ${bot.name} database has been recovered!`);
            start();
        } else {
            exec(`docker volume create bot-${bot.name}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(` ${bot.name} database has been created!`);
                    start();
                } else console.error(err);
            });
        }
        
    });

});

};

const restart = process.argv.includes('-restart');

if (restart) {
    console.log(' Shutting down all bots...');
    bots.forEach((bot) => {
        exec(`docker-compose -p bot-${bot.name} stop`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (!err) {
                exec(`docker-compose -p bot-${bot.name} rm -f`, (err, stdout, stderr) => { 
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log(` Bot ${bot.name} has been shut down and 
removed.`);
                    } else {
                        console.log(` Failed to remove containers for bot 
${bot.name}`);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    recreate();
}
```

and and docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  vinted-discord-bot:
    image: vinted-discord-bot:3.17
    environment:
      VINTED_BOT_ADMIN_IDS: "${VINTED_BOT_ADMIN_IDS}"
      VINTED_BOT_TOKEN: "${VINTED_BOT_TOKEN}"
      POSTGRES_DB: vinted_bot
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
    external:
     name: bot-${BOT}
```

and finally the bots.json :

```
[
    {
    "name": "thenameofthebot",
    "token": "thetokenofthebot",
    "adminIDs": "theidoftheadminserver"
    }
]
```

Here is a screen of the error (in French):

[image: errorscreen]

You can find it on: https://github.com/Androz2091/vinted-discord-bot.

Comment: The error "X is not recognized as an internal command or external command, an executable program or a command file" has hundreds of duplicates here. It is a Windows console error, and it means that Windows can't find the command that is being run.

Comment: However, if one digs a bit deeper, have a look at the command format: `BOT=${bot.name} VINTED_BOT_ADMIN_IDS=${bot.adminIDs} VINTED_BOT_TOKEN=${bot.token} docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml` - basically the `BOT=x VINTED_BOT_ADMIN_IDS=y VINTED_BOT_TOKEN=z` bit is trying to supply environment variables to a command, but Windows does not support this format.

Comment: What you could do is to set up a copy of Ubuntu in VirtualBox on your Windows computer, and then run this - and then I think it would work. It basically needs a Linux host.

Comment: @halfer Hi, but when I run the program on ubuntu I don't get an error but it displays this and nothing happens :  Checking existing volumes...
 Starting MaetisVintedBot...
 MaetisVintedBot database has been recovered!

Comment: It looks like it has got further than last time. Either it is working, or you'll have to find out what is wrong with it, or it is not well-tested software. Consider spending some more time on the problem now that you have solved one problem, and ask a new question on Stack Overflow if you can produce a full fault report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a binary for your program. In Node.js, you can create a binary in `package.json`.

**Step 1:** In your main file, you need to add a shebang (`#!`), and `/usr/bin/env node` after that. **Important! This must be on the very first line of your main file.**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

**Step 2:** In your `package.json` file, add the following two keys, replacing `index.js` with your own main file.

```json
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "BOT": "./index.js"
  },
}
```

**Step 3:** Run the following command to apply it to your computer.

```
npm link
```

*EDIT: If the above command doesn't work, run the following command.*

```
npm install -g .
```

---

And that's it! It should work when you run the following command.

```
BOT
```

Comment: Do hashbangs work in Windows?

Comment: It works for me when I do it.

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.

Comment: @maetiscrepin: can you explain to Arnav _how_ it doesn't work? "Doesn't work" is not in itself a fault report, and if that is all the detail you offer, your helper will have to send to you a round of question to elicit enough information to work out why it does not work. Things like console output, logs, error messages are essential, and are ideally supplied straight away, rather than waiting for someone to ask for them. Thanks!

Comment: @maetiscrepin Does the edited solution work for you now?

Comment: @ArnavThorat Hi, thanks for the edit but when I do " node index.js" I have an error: Unexpected string in JSON at position 143
    at parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Can you share the `index.js` file via CodePen or editing your question?